# Set image transparency with VBA in Excel

Tags: image, vba, excel

Is there a way to apply some transparency to an image using a VBA script? I have recorded a "macro" and it seems that artistic effects aren't recorded. I have found how to make it for shapes, but not for images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires several steps:

1. Place an AutoShape (like a rectangle) on the worksheet
2. Embed your actual picture in the rectangle using:  `.ShapeRange.Fill.UserPicture`
3. Adjust the transparency using:  `.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code: Remove Background image and use tool picture format, set transparent color in Excel.

```
Sub RemoveBackground()
  Dim selectedPicture As Picture
  Set selectedPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures("Picture 3")
' Set the transparent color of the picture
  With selectedPicture.ShapeRange.PictureFormat
    .TransparentBackground = True
    .TransparencyColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
  End With 
End Sub
```

```
  Sub RemoveShapes()
  ' Select the image you want to remove the background from
  Dim selectedImage As Shape
  Set selectedImage = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Image1")     ' Set the transparent color of the image 

  With selectedImage.PictureFormat
    .TransparentBackground = msoTrue
    .TransparencyColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
  End With
End Sub
```