# Using the Form Scrollbar to Control Image Transparency in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling in making a form scrollbar to control the image transparency. To be specific, I've got two images that I'm linking to two buttons. Hide/show buttons, and I want the scrollbar to control the image transparency as shown in the image below. Your help would be appreciated. I can't wrap my head around to code it.

[image: Scrollbar to control transparency]

Comment: Not quite a duplicate but closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22158502/4996248

Comment: @John Coleman, I looked at that it's not related. As it doesn't show how the scroll bar can be linked to transparency.

Comment: As soon as you can use VBA to control the transparency, you can use that VBA in the event-handler of the control, no?

Comment: @John Coleman. I don't understand your comment. Could you please elaborate on how to code the scrollbar to control shape transparency. I can put the image inside a shape like a box and then control its transparency.

Comment: I was responding to your statement that they weren't related. Using VBA you can take a variable and use it to control transparency -- and the linked question shows you how. Controls such as scrollbars have event handlers that fire when the control is used. These event handlers can be used to change the values of variables -- with e.g. the new values fed into the code which controls transparency. Perhaps your question is -- how do I write event handlers for scrollbars in VBA?

Comment: @John Coleman-I feel like you know my question very well. It's obvious that I don't know what "event handler" is. Do you have to make that hard for me? I just want to know how to tell the scrollbar to control the transparency. Can you help me with that?

Comment: From you original question I assumed that you were familiar with using controls in VBA but didn't know how to use them specifically for transparency, so it wasn't obvious that you were unfamiliar with event handlers until you said so right now. An important question -- are these *Form* controls or are they *Active-X* controls? From the user's perspective they are more or less interchangeable, but the VBA to use them is fairly different.

Comment: @John Coleman. They are Form control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a low-tech approach.

1) Create a rectangle and fill it with your picture. This doesn't require any VBA.

2) Insert the scrollbar and, using the properties, link your scrollbar to a cell with the default 0-100 range of the scrollbar's values. For example, in the following picture I linked it to `J20`:

[image]

Then, in a standard code module put:

```
Sub SetTransparency()
    Sheets(1).Shapes("Rectangle 1").Fill.Transparency = Sheets(1).Range("J20") / 100
End Sub
```

(With of course things like Sheets(1), "Rectangle 1" and "J20" to be adjusted to match your situation)

Then - all you have to do is right click on the control and select `Assign Macro` to assign this macro to your control. It can be used like:

[image]

Possibly unfortunately (depending on your desires) the transparency doesn't change continuously as you scroll. AKAIK, you would need to use Active-X controls for that.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue. As you mentioned it doesn't change the transparency contentiously. I would like to be able to change the transparency dynamically by moving the scroll bar to the left, or right. Do you you recommend using the Active-x scroll bar instead? I can do that if you think that solves our issue.

Comment: Actually I found the answer. Right click on the scroll bar and go to format properties. Then put a reference cell. In this example we would put "J20" as a reference cell. This should make the scroll bar dynamic.